# Trouble plotting MNIST digits

Tags: python, matplotlib, computer-vision, mnist

I am trying to load and visualize MNIST digits, but I am getting digits with shifted pixel

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mnist_data  = open('data/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte', 'rb')

image_size = 28
num_images = 4

buf = mnist_data.read(num_images * image_size * image_size)
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32)
data = data.reshape(num_images, image_size, image_size)

_, axarr1 = plt.subplots(2,2)
axarr1[0, 0].imshow(data[0])
axarr1[0, 1].imshow(data[1])
axarr1[1, 0].imshow(data[2])
axarr1[1, 1].imshow(data[3])
```

[image: MNIST]

Can anyone tell me why it's happening code seems fine, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say where you obtained the MNIST data, but, [if it is formatted like the original data set](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), you seem to have forgotten to extract the header before trying to access the data:

```
image_size = 28
num_images = 4

mnist_data = open('train-images-idx3-ubyte', 'rb')

mnist_data.seek(16) # skip over the first 16 bytes that correspond to the header
buf = mnist_data.read(num_images * image_size * image_size)
data = np.frombuffer(buf, dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.float32)
data = data.reshape(num_images, image_size, image_size)

_, axarr1 = plt.subplots(2,2)
axarr1[0, 0].imshow(data[0])
axarr1[0, 1].imshow(data[1])
axarr1[1, 0].imshow(data[2])
axarr1[1, 1].imshow(data[3])
```

[image]